# Merge json arrays created by a while loop in php, fetching values from a database

Tags: php, arrays, json, while-loop

I am getting two JSON arrays that I need merged each time a while loop runs a fetch from my database. This is the structure array result I am getting as of now:

```
{id=1,cid=1,fname=Lorna,vorname=King,gender=female,dob=1985,company=helsana,monthly_amount=150},
{id=2,cid=1,fname=Brian,vorname=King,gender=male,dob=2007,company=helsana,monthly_amount=100}
```

I need it to look like this:

```
{id={1,2},cid={1,1},fname={Lorna,Brian},vorname={King,King},gender={female,male},dob={1985,2007},company={helsana,helsana},monthly_amount={150,100}}
```

Here is the PHP code that I am using:

```
<?php
include_once "conn.php";
$show= $mysqli->query("SELECT id,cid,fname,vorname,gender,dob,company,monthly_amount FROM family where cid = '1' ");
$arr = array();
while($row = $show->fetch_assoc()){
    $arr[] = $row;
}
$json_response = json_encode($arr, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP);
echo $str = substr($json_response, 1,-1);
?>
```

Am kinda new to this please someone help me out.

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? You're basically asking for help totally mangling your data!

Comment: You are right it ruins the data. I just want the array arranged in a way I can pick each record and the values associated with it.

Comment: Why can't you do that now? I see no need to pivot it.

Comment: I need it actually in this format { 1={id:1, cid:1 fname=Lorna, vorname:King, gender:female, dob:1985, company:helsana, monthly_amount:100}, 2={id:2, cid:1 fname=Brian, vorname:King, gender:male, dob:2005, company:helsana, monthly_amount:150} }. Am struggling to figure out how to do that right now.

Comment: Eh? That's not at all what you asked for in your question.

Comment: I know, that's how I should have asked it. Am new to this so just bare with my armature knowledge on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use new array_column function from PHP to get what you need . Note that JSON will be of structure {id=[1,2],cid=[1,1],fname=[Lorna,Brian]...  so [] instead of {}

```
<?php
  include_once "conn.php";
  $show= $mysqli->query("SELECT id,cid,fname,vorname,gender,dob,company,monthly_amount FROM           family where cid = '1' ");
  $arr = array();
  while($row = $show->fetch_assoc()){ $arr[] = $row; } 
//
$final = array();
foreach ( array_keys($arr[0]) as $fieldName){
    $final[$fieldName] = array_column($arr, $fieldName);
}

$json_response =  json_encode($final,JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP);
echo $str = substr($json_response, 1,-1);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously recommend against what you're asking. There's a good reason why those results are separate.

Anyway to answer your question here's a way - but *again* unless there's a specific reason why you want to so this I'd think instead about how you are handling the JSON instead.

Here, I'm just using the first row to set up the array and then manually concatenating the data.

```
<?php
include_once "conn.php";
$show= $mysqli->query("SELECT id,cid,fname,vorname,gender,dob,company,monthly_amount FROM           family where cid = '1' ");
$arr = array();
$arr[] = $show->fetch_assoc();
while($row = $show->fetch_assoc()){
  $arr['id'] .= ',' . $row['id'];
  $arr['cid'] .= ',' . $row['cid'];
  $arr['dob'] .= ',' . $row['dob'];
  $arr['company'] = ',' . $row['company'];
  $arr['monthly_amount'] = ',' . $row['monthly_amount'];
  $arr['vorname'] = ',' . $row['vorname'];
  $arr['fname'] = ',' . $row['fname'];
} 
$json_response = json_encode($arr, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP);
echo $str = substr($json_response, 1,-1);
```

Comment: You are right it ruins the data. I just want the array arranged in a way I can pick each record and the values associated with it.

Comment: You are right its not advisable to put the data in that format. I just want the array arranged in a way I can pick each record and the values associated with it. I need it actually in this format   { 1={id:1, cid:1 fname=Lorna, vorname:King, gender:female, dob:1985, company:helsana, monthly_amount:100}, 2={id:2, cid:1 fname=Brian, vorname:King, gender:male, dob:2005, company:helsana, monthly_amount:150} }. How can this be done?

Comment: @CalebNasio - that's kind of what you have already. You're encoding an array that you can easily parse in JavaScript. Have a look here and hopefully you'll see what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/2pxvp624/